# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser returning div as an array

Tags: php, parsing, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I'm using PHP and simple HTML DOM Parser to try and grab song lyrics from a website. The song lyrics are held in a div with the class "lyrics". Here's the code I'm using to try and grab the div and display it. Currently it only returns "Array" onto my webpage. When I jsonify the array I can see that the array is empty.

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$data = file_get_contents("https://example.com/songlyrics");
$html = str_get_html($data);
$lyr = $html->find('div.lyrics');
echo $lyr;
?>
```

I know that the Simple HTML Dom Parser is being included correctly, and I have no problem displaying the full webpage when I echo $html with some small changes to the code, however I can't seem to echo just this div. Is there something wrong with my code? Why is $lyr returning an array?

Comment: most likely its a collection of classes, point to the first element, `->find('div.lyrics, 0')`, mind the second argument, then `echo`

Comment: @Ghost thanks, that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code.

> Why is $lyr returning an array?

It's because a class is considered to be used multiple times. If you `var_dump($lyr)` instead, you should see all the div-elements found with that class name.

You can either `echo $lyr[0]` or you can `$html->find('div.lyrics',0)` to select a specific div element.

Comment: var_dump will be useful in the future. I'm not too familiar with PHP so that would have saved me a bit of time. The comment Ghost left already solved my problem but since this is an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: That's not quite it. `find` always returns an array unless you use the second argument. It's a confusing thing you have to get used to. Also, don't use var_dump, you'll see why not if you try it.

Comment: @pguardiario Thanks for the info. I do see why not to use var_dump now lol.